# Terms related to megasporogenesis

Tags: botany, reproduction

Well, I am not able to understand the exact difference between megasporocyte and archesporium. Also I'm not quite able to get, how or precisely from where do these arise?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relation  to *angiospermic megasporogenesis*, archesporium cell is the precursor of Megasporocyte.

> [Archesporium](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/archesporium) is defined as   the cell or group of cells from which spore mother cells develops
>
> The megasporocyte is the cell(or the tissue) which **directly** produces
>    the megaspores.

In most angiosperm, the nucellar tissue within the ovule first differentiates into a single archesporial cell, the ancestor of the Megaspore Mother cell(MMC). In certain species, this archesporial cell may itself act as the MMC undergoing meiosis to produce the megaspores. in such cases, the archesporial cell and the megasporocyte (another name for MMC) is the same.

But in some species, the archesporial cell first undergoes a periclinic division producing two cells which further produce the parietal layer (covering of the megaspore) and a single sporogenous cell. This cell acts as the MMC, and is the megasporocyte.

Thus the archesporial cell may or may not be the same as the megasporocyte. It could be the ancestor of megasporocyte.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What I was wondering is that, as you said that archesporium can be a group of cells than would all those cells develop into a MMC or is there any type of differentiation among them so as to satisfy the requirements of any one cell which would develop into a MMC?

Comment: When archesporium is a group of cell, two things can happen. One is that most of them form the parietal layer, and a single cell matures into MMC. Or if the archesporial cell is in the male anther, most of them mature into PMC (pollen mother cell).